# Code appears as comments in R?

Tags: r, comments

I know that:

```
# this is a comment
code <- ("this is code")
```

Can anyone tell me how it is possible and for some R code to appear in green (like a comment)
even though I have not stated a # in front of the code? The code can be run without any 
trouble, that is the strange part?

One of my students had that "problem", and I couldn't figure out why the code appeared green?

Thanks in advance for an answer :)

Kind Regards 
Maria

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your editor, not with your code! What editor are you using?

Comment: If the code is running it's clearly not commented. Which brings us back to what Wormbourne said: The syntax highlighting is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that your student didn't have that exact problem. Instead, what I suspect happened was they had missed off some speech marks before the comment. For example, this code

```
x = "fred
#Some stuff
# this is a comment
code = ("this is code")
```

in Rstudio makes everything "green":

[image]

Comment: ahh, that's probably the reason. Thank you so much for your answer - I will pass the knowledge on :)